# Upgrading mobile framework to be compatible with appium 2.0, tested the build on appium inspector and it works and now i want to open it via framework

Tags: java, appium-ios

This is the errors am getting when trying to start appium programmaticaly

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void loadSystemProperties()' of abstract class org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:505)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:90)
    at com.automation.base.BaseClass.startServer(BaseClass.java:118)
    at com.automation.test.ApplicationContextInitializer.init(ApplicationContextInitializer.java:61)
    at com.automation.test.ApplicationContextInitializer.onExecutionStart(ApplicationContextInitializer.java:98)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runExecutionListeners(TestNG.java:1075)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1026)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109)
```

with the old version of appium it worked but with the new one it throws this exception